# PostgreSQL database design on multiple disks

Tags: postgresql

Currently I've one physical machine with few SSD disks and PostgreSQL fresh installation: I'll load ~1-2Tb of data in few distinct tables (they've not interconnection between themselves) where each table comprises distinct data entity.

I am thinking about two approaches:

1. Create DB (with corresponding table for data entity) on each disk for each entity.
2. Create one DB but store each table for corresponding data entity on separate disks.

So, my questions are as follows: what approach is preferred and which can be achieved with less cost?

Comment: How about 3) Put the disks into one logical volume using some kind of JBOD or LVM?

Answer (score 2):

You can answer the question yourself.

- Are the data used by the same application?
- Are the data from these tables joined?
- Should these tables always be started and stopped together and have the same PostgreSQL version?

If yes, then they had best be stored together in a single database. Create three logical volumes that is striped across your SSDs: one for the data, one for `pg_wal`, one for the logs.

If not, you might be best off with a database or a database cluster per table.

Comment: Thank you! Replies are as follows: 1) No 2) No 3) Preferably instances should run together. So, I should go for second way?

Comment: Then perhaps several databases in a single instance.